# select within if statement in SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement, select

```
if (select authorized.on from authorized join log on( authorized.card_id =log.card_id)) = now() then
insert into entry(access) values('granted');
end if;
```

"select" returns a date. however, the statement does work if i placed it in an if statement.

Comment: What kind of DB is it?

Comment: Why don't you select data in some variable then use that variable to check in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do it the other way, do an `INSERT` with `SELECT`, where the `SELECT` returns one row with the value `'granted'` if the conditions are fulfilled:

```
insert into entry(access)
    select distinct 'granted'
    from authorized
      join log on (authorized.card_id = log.card_id)
    where authorized.on = now()
```

If the `SELECT` conditions never are fulfilled, no row will be inserted.